# PHP not receiveing data from Ajax Json Call

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am attempting to insert user info into MySQL. I have created the following ajax call that appears to be creating the data in JSON however when I run `print_r( json_encode( $_GET));` it shows an empty array.

In the debugger it appears that the call is including the data in the url:

```
results.php?method=submitScore&score=1&username=bob
```

main.html

```
function getData(obj,callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'results.php',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: obj
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(callback != null)
            callback(data);
    });
}
```

results.php

```
<?php

class Results {
    public $data;
    public $success = true;
    public $errorMessage;
}
 print_r( json_encode( $_GET));

$func = $_GET['method'];
$obj = new Results();



switch ($func) {

        case "getHighScores":
        $conn = new  mysqli('localhost','Username','Password','DB');
        if (!$conn->connect_errno) {
            $high = "SELECT * FROM HighScores ORDER BY Score LIMIT 10";
            $scores = $conn->query($high);
            $arr = array();
            while ($row = $scores->fetch_assoc()){
                $arr[] = $row;
            }
            $obj->data = $arr;
            echo json_encode($obj);
        }
        break;
    case "submitScore":
        $userName = $_GET["username"];
        $score = $_GET["score"];
        $conn = new  mysqli('localhost','W01214804','Kylecs!','W01214804');
        if (!$conn->connect_errno) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO HIGHSCORES VALUES('" . $userName . "', '" . $score . "')";
            $conn->query($query);
    }
        break;
    default:
        echo "Invalid method";
        break;







    }

?>
```

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: Yes "results.php?method=submitScore&score=1&username=bob" is a portion of the request from the developer tools. Yes I have included "<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>" I am not seeing any additional errors. Yes it is on a web server.

Comment: What about just `print_r($_GET);`?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Why are you using json_encode inside print_r? You're not sending JSON to the server. Nor does your later code attempt to interpret anything as JSON. Also you haven't actually said whether the rest of the code works - does it insert into the database as you expect? It could simply be a problem with the way you're trying to view the GET array and nothing else.

Comment: When I run print_r($_GET); the output is "Array ( )" I appreciate the help as I am just learning all of this. No it is not inserting in to the database.

Comment: If the ajax call is calling `results.php?method=submitScore&score=1&username=bob` as a GET request with all those variables, then it seems pretty much impossible that PHP could report the array as being empty. Are you _sure_ that it's sending them? Have you looked in your browser's network tab to examine the ajax request and see what is actually being sent to results.php?